# Implement MATLAB algorithm in Spartan 3E

Tags: matlab, vhdl, fpga

I am new to FPGA. Is it possible to implement MATLAB algorithm in Spartan 3E without using RS232?

Comment: Yes, yes you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RS232 is a connection port for things like UART.

If you are asking about downloading matlab code into an FPGA, then no. You can create simulink models and include them into your designs at compile time; but this has nothing to do with RS232.

Answer (score 0):

I will partially agree with the accepted answer, that MatLab and RS232 are two independent and completely irrelevant things.

On the other hand, it is absolutely possible to implement a MatLab algorithm in FPGA. The first method which came in mind is by using some High-Level Synthesis tool. These tools will take your Matlab code (or simulink models) and convert them into fully synthesizable VHDL or Verilog code, which then can be implemented on the FPGA.

Take a look here: http://community.em.avnet.com/t5/Programmable-Logic/How-do-I-implement-my-MATLAB-algorithm-in-an-FPGA/td-p/1112.

Comment: I agree it's absolutely possible. Spartan 3E is a pretty old device, so it could be that it won't be well supported by HLS tools. If we're just talking about possible, then you could even implement a simple CPU and execute instructions on that.